# Does using scala's type declaration for clarity have and drawbacks?

Tags: scala

For example, suppose we have:

```
object Types {
   type ObjectMap = collection.Map[String, Any]
}

class X {
  def toObjectMap(x:Any): ObjectMap = x.asInstanceOf[Types.ObjectMap] 
}
```

Does this have any additional runtime penalties compared to:

```
class X {
  def toObjectMap(x:Any): collection.Map[String, Any]= x.asInstanceOf[collection.Map[String, Any]] 
}
```

Comment: It is merely an alias and does not in any way change the generated code. Nor does it create any additional type safety. If you `type Glorch = Int` you cannot prevent any old `Int` from being used where you specified `Glorch`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't expect it to, but you know it's like, really easy to try it out.

```
scala> :javap -prv X

  public scala.collection.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object> toObjectMap(java.lang.Object);
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_1       
         1: checkcast     #9                  // class scala/collection/Map
         4: areturn       
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
               0       5     0  this   L$line9/$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$X;
               0       5     1     x   Ljava/lang/Object;
      LineNumberTable:
        line 53: 0
    Signature: #75                          // (Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/Map<Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;>;

  public scala.collection.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object> toObjectMap2(java.lang.Object);
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_1       
         1: checkcast     #9                  // class scala/collection/Map
         4: areturn       
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
               0       5     0  this   L$line9/$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$X;
               0       5     1     x   Ljava/lang/Object;
      LineNumberTable:
        line 54: 0
    Signature: #75                          // (Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/Map<Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Type aliases are just shorthand. The compiler expands the alias and from then on, proceeds precisely as if you had written the type out yourself. (As Som's answer shows, at least for your particular example.)